# Python and Selenium: StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium

I know the element may be refreshed but I am still locating the old element.  However, I don't know how to modify it!  Please help!

```
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from lxml import etree

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.boci-pru.com.hk/english/mpf/mpfdisclaimer.aspx?to=http://www.boci-pru.com.hk/english/mpf/prices.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="I agree and wish to proceed"]').click()
driver.get("http://www.boci-pru.com.hk/english/mpf/prices_hist.aspx")
date = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
fromday = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="fromday"]'))
frommonth = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="frommonth"]'))
fromyear = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="fromyear"]'))
fromyear.select_by_value(str(date.year))
frommonth.select_by_value(str(date.month))
fromday.select_by_value(str(date.day))
selFund = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="selFund_code"]')
all_funds = selFund.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
all_funds = [f for f in all_funds if len(f.get_attribute("value")) >= 2 and len(f.get_attribute("value")) < 6]

for fund in all_funds:
    fund.click()        # <--- this is where the issue starts
    print(fund.get_attribute("value"))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="go"]').click()
```

Comment: i dont know the Python case, but in java we have ExpectedConditions so we can wait for objects to appear. it seems that all page loading is done by script, so selenium doesnt wait for the page to appear. so before you get the staleElementReference, try to wait for the object to be there

Comment: it seems to me you are submitting the form and then clicking on an element from previous page..?

Comment: @Aprillion No, all elements are on the same page, as least look like on the same page.

Comment: in that case, it is the second most likely that clicking on "go" button will update DOM and you might need to `find` the elements again in every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 0):

if the elements are refreshed after you click on the "go" button, then you have to `find` the elements again - there is probably a better way, but the most straight forward adaptation of your code would be something like this:

```
i = 0;
while True:
    selFund = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="selFund_code"]')
    all_funds = selFund.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    all_funds = [f for f in all_funds if len(f.get_attribute("value")) >= 2 and len(f.get_attribute("value")) < 6]
    try:
        all_funds[i].click()
        print(fund.get_attribute("value"))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="go"]').click()
        i += 1
    except IndexError:  # if i > len(all_funds)
        break
```

assuming the order of options does not change between iterations..

Answer (score -2):

Use "TRY" and "EXCEPT" block as shown below:

```
for fund in all_funds:
    try:
        fund.click() 
        print(fund.get_attribute("value"))
    except:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="go"]').click()
```

Comment: ..why would anyone do this?

Comment: You have seen a StaleElementReferenceException in your tests. And the most common causes for this exception is thrown in one of two cases, the first being more common than the second:
• The element has been deleted entirely.
• The element is no longer attached to the DOM. 

So, the easiest way to check if an element exists is to simply call find_element inside a try/except.

Comment: a) I did not see anything in any tests, b) if anything, it would be `except StaleElementReferenceException:`, c) but why do you think it would be a good idea to click on random elements after getting an unexpected exception??